# PHP how to remove words from string and add another words?

Tags: php, string

I'm trying to achieve the following thing:

I have a url which is http://dev.example.com/state/store

I wan't just to get http://dev.example.com/ and add another-state/another-store.

I know that the last part is a concact, so that is not a problem, but how can I remove the state/store part?

Greetings!

Comment: sorry no, I'm using Magento framework, so I'm getting the base url, but in string format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **[parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** function allows you to extract the various components (scheme, host, path, etc.) of a URL from a string.

```php
$url = parse_url("http://dev.example.com/state/store");
```

The function contains an associative array containing the different URL components. You'd want to look at the URL scheme and host.

Alternatively, you can provide a component integer as the second parameter (see the docs link above for the different values), to return a single component of the supplied URL.